# The criteria when fibre product irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry

All varieties are over algebraically closed field of characteristic zero and irreducible.

Let $\varphi\colon X\to S_2$ be a morphism of varieties. Assume $\psi\colon S_1\to S_2$ is a morphism.

> Is it true that $X\times_{S_2}S_1$ is irreducible if a)$\psi$ is flat b) $\psi$ is smooth?

Edit: As it have been shown in the answer the question is no, even if we assume both $\psi$ and $\varphi$ to be smooth and finite.

On the other hand the statement is true if $\psi$ is flat with irreducible fibers and $X$ is irreducible.

Comment: If $S_1$ is a disjoint union of several copies of $S_2$, then the fiber product is of course not irreducible. But it is stated in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267258/irreducibility-of-fiber-product-of-irreducible-varieties-via-dominant-morphisms that it suffices to assume also that $\psi$ has geometrically irreducible fibers.

Comment: My $S_1$ and $S_2$ are irreducible. I understand that if $\varphi$ is an embedding of some point, then for irreducibility of the fibre product, $\psi$ should has irreducible fibers. But let us assume that $\varphi$ is dominant. What is wrong when $\psi$ has reducible fibers in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No!

Consider flat family $\psi\colon V(xy-z)\to\mathbb{A}^1_z$, and $\varphi\colon \mathbb{A}^0\to\mathbb{A}^1$ be the inclusion of a point.  Then the fibre corresponding to $z=0$ is reducible $V(xy)$.

---

**Edit**:
Much simpler example in discussion below $\psi,\varphi\colon\mathbb{G}_m\to\mathbb{G}_m$ be the squaring map.  Then the fibred product $\mathbb{G}_m\times_{\mathbb{G}_m}\mathbb{G}_m$ is two copies of $\mathbb{G}_m$.

Comment: Yes you are correct. What will happen if I assume $\varphi$ to be dominant? And this is only a) I have another item about smooth $\psi$

Comment: In fact a much simpler example: the squaring map $\mathbb{G}_m\to\mathbb{G}_m$ is smooth and the fibres are 2 closed points.  I'll have to think about the dominant $\varphi$ case.

Comment: Actually the same map works.  $\mathbb{G}_m\to\mathbb{G}_m$ squaring for both maps $\varphi,\psi$ and the fibred product is two disjoint copies of $\mathbb{G}_m$.

Comment: And the second map is dominant and even finite！